# Ultrasonic Sensor receiving Side

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I'm doing my project regarding 40khz ultrasonic sensor which will be used to get accurate distance measurements. I have a separate transmitter and receiver. I want to get the time between the moment my transmitter transmitted the waves and the time my receiver received it. However, I couldn't actually make it work. Does any of you give me a code that would help me transmit and receive the 40khz waves and get the time in between so I could use it to compute for the distance?Thank you in advance. I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What is your exact hardware? Most commercial US sensors I know have their own measuring implemented on board.

Comment: @mystery what about the [`HC-SR04`](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13959)?

Comment: I know that one quite well. It should serve OPs wish for example code https://github.com/sparkfun/HC-SR04_UltrasonicSensor/blob/master/Firmware/HC-SR04_UltrasonicSensorExample/HC-SR04_UltrasonicSensorExample.ino

Comment: I'm using arduino uno, and separate ultrasonic transmitter and receiver. I'm not using any commercially available ultrasonic sensor

Answer (score 1):

This is the most basic ultrasound pulse and receive code. I wrote it to work with the `HC-SR04` modules; so hopefully it will work fro you too as those also sound at `40khz`.

The main functionality comes from the [`pulseIn()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/pulsein/) funciton.

```
#define TRIGPIN 9
#define ECHOPIN 10

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(TRIGPIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ECHOPIN, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, LOW);

  uint16_t duration = pulseIn(ECHOPIN, HIGH, 4000);
  int distance = (duration*.0343)/2;
  Serial.println(distance);
}
```

---

Note that you will need to adjust the `4000` (`μs`) to whatever timeout in you want (or emit entirely if you don't want it).

Comment: Hi Sir! Sadly, I'm not using any commercially available ultrasonic sensor like HC-SR04. I have separate transmitter and receiver transducer Sir.

Comment: @JeniferRicalde That is fine, can you provide a link to these? The code will still work assuming the transmitter and receiver are simply digital outputs (i.e. send HIGH to transmit sound on the transmitter and the receiver outputs HIGH when it receives).

Comment: Sir, will it be ok if I ask for your email?I wish to send the code. I cannot attach it in here

Comment: Why not? Just insert into the question like I have in my answer the `.ino` file.  Or make a link with https://pastebin.com/

Comment: I'm sending 8 pulses of 40khz waves then the receiver will measure the voltage peak of the wave it received so that it may know the time interval.however, i'm not quite sure if my code is right

Comment: here's the link:
https://pastebin.com/4chsLQ6R

Comment: I used, Mr. Kerry Wong's code

Comment: @JeniferRicalde I am sorry but since you have just copied [someone's code](http://www.kerrywong.com/2011/01/22/a-sensitive-diy-ultrasonic-range-sensor/) it is especially difficult to debug without being able to try things out (since I don't have that setup). However there are two things: you can use the `delay()` function to delay in milliseconds and use `delayMicroseconds()` for micros - there is no need to write your own `delayMilliseconds()` function because `delay()` already works. And secondly, I recommend you use the `Serial` lib to print the readings from the receiver to help debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 'a code', but what you can do is using a timer set to 40 kHz and send the pulses you need. .

If nothing else needs to be done (nor in the future) you can use a delay function.

Also check the pulseIn function from Arduino, you can use this convenience function for the checking the result.